# Why can't I rig SciPy's constrained optimization for integer programming?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

[I've read that integer programming is either very tricky or not possible with SciPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180822/integer-step-size-in-scipy-optimize-minimize)  and that I probably need to use something like zibopt to do it in Python .  But I really thought I could do it by creating one "is binary" constraint for each element in a vector being optimized by SciPy.

To do that, I utilized the closure trick from http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures
and created one constraint function for each element, like so:

```
def get_binary_constraints(vector, indices_to_make_binary=None):
    indices_to_make_binary = indices_to_make_binary or range(len(vector))
    for i in indices_to_make_binary:
        def ith_element_is_binary(vector, index=i):
            return vector[index] == 0 or vector[index] == 1
        yield ith_element_is_binary

test_vector = scipy.array([0.5, 1, 3])
constraints = list(get_binary_constraints(test_vector))
for constraint in constraints:
    print constraint(test_vector)
```

which prints:

```
False
True
False
```

Then I modified get_binary_constraints for fmin_cobyla, whose constraints are a ["sequence of functions that all must be >=0"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla).

```
def get_binary_constraints(vector, indices_to_make_binary=None):
    indices_to_make_binary = indices_to_make_binary or range(len(vector))
    for i in indices_to_make_binary:
        def ith_element_is_binary(vector, index=i):
            return int(vector[index] == 0 or vector[index] == 1) - 1
        yield ith_element_is_binary
```

which prints the following for the same test vector [0.5, 1, 3]:

```
-1
0
-1
```

So, only the 2nd value in the array will meet the condition >= 0.

Then, I set up a very simple optimization problem as follows:

```
from scipy import optimize
import scipy

def get_binary_constraints(vector, indices_to_make_binary=None):
    indices_to_make_binary = indices_to_make_binary or range(len(vector))
    for i in indices_to_make_binary:
        def ith_element_is_binary(vector, index=i):
            return int(vector[index] == 0 or vector[index] == 1) - 1
        yield ith_element_is_binary

def objective_function(vector):
    return scipy.sum(vector)

def main():
    guess_vector = scipy.zeros(3)
    constraints = list(get_binary_constraints(guess_vector))
    result = optimize.fmin_cobyla(objective_function, guess_vector, constraints)
    print result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is what I get:

```
Return from subroutine COBYLA because the MAXFUN limit has been reached.

NFVALS = 1000   F =-8.614066E+02    MAXCV = 1.000000E+00
X =-2.863657E+02  -2.875204E+02  -2.875204E+02
[-286.36573349 -287.52043407 -287.52043407]
```

Before I go use R's LPSolve package or install zipobt for this, I'd really like to see if I can just use SciPy.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not possible to do in SciPy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that, as unintuitive as it may seem, [Integer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns) is a fundamentally more difficult problem than Linear Programming with real numbers. Someone in the SO thread you linked to mentions that SciPy uses the [Simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) algorithm. The algorithm doesn't work for integer programming. You have to use a different algorithm.

If you do find a way to use Simplex to solve integer programming efficiently, you've solved the [P=NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_=_NP_problem) problem, which is worth [US$1,000,000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems#P_versus_NP) to the first person to solve.

Comment: One simplification you could do would be to solve it for real numbers then round down. This wouldn't give you the optimal solution, but it would most likely give you something that is reasonably good. Could something like this work for your needs?

Comment: The other thread uses Nelder-Mead, but also `fmin_cobyla` used here is simplex-based.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the second paragraph of this answer is wrong. If you could solve integer programming problems efficiently with the simplex method, you haven't proven P=NP unless you also prove that your hypothetical integer-simplex method runs in polynomial time. Although there are polynomial algorithms for linear programming, it's not known whether there is a polynomial simplex method for LP.