# Scipy optimize specify parameter step size, false positive convergence

Tags: python, image, optimization, scipy

I'm using scipy optimize for a biomedical imaging application. I'm trying to write an algorithm that will align two images by finding the affine transform (shifting, scaling, and rotation, in this case) between the two. I'm using an optimizer to minimize the difference between the two images. The parameters I'm trying to optimize are the x and y shifts, rotation about the center of the image, and the scaling in the x and y dimensions. Ideally, the step sizes would all be close to whole numbers rather than on the order of 1e-6 (current step size). Is there any way to specify the minimum step sizes used for the parameters in scipy optimize?

I'm currently mapping them to the proper order of magnitude, but this only works for a parameter or two at a time for the Nelder-Mead method. (I'm aiming to use L-BFGS-B because of the gradient, but that's a whole other set of problems at the moment.) Adding more parameters causes the optimization to think a misaligned image is the correct answer. Is this "false positive" result typical of scipy optimize? Is there any way to force more accuracy aside from changing the tolerance?

Working code:

```
class toy():
    def __init__(self, img1, img2):
        self.original = img1
        self.shifted = img2

    def find_affine(self, parameters):
        # extract parameters
        x = 0
        y = 0
        r = 0.0
        sx = 1.0
        sy = 1.0
        # x = int(parameters[0]*10000)
        # y = int(parameters[1]*10000)
        # r = int(parameters[2]*10000)
        # sx = 1.0 + abs(round(parameters[3]*1000, 1))
        # sy = 1.0 + abs(round(parameters[4]*1000, 1))

        print "Updated parameters: [" + str(x) + ", " + str(y) + ", " + str(r) + ", " + str(sx) + ", " + str(sy) + "]"

        # image data
        original_dims = [len(self.original), len(self.original[0])]
        shifted_dims = [len(self.shifted), len(self.shifted[0])]
        mod_orig = self.original

        # set up rotation
        if r != 0.0:
            rotation = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((original_dims[0]/2, original_dims[1]/2), r, 1)
            mod_orig = cv2.warpAffine(mod_orig, rotation, (len(self.original), len(self.original[0])))

        # set up scaling
        if sx != 1.0 or sy != 1.0:
            dims = [int(round(sx*original_dims[0])), int(round(sy*original_dims[1]))]
            mod_orig = cv2.resize(mod_orig, (dims[0], dims[1]), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            original_dims = [len(mod_orig), len(mod_orig[0])]

        print "New dimensions: " + str(len(mod_orig)) + " " + str(len(mod_orig[0]))

        # set up translation
        shift = [y*sy, x*sx, 0]  # does this need to be scaled?

        # convert to pixels
        # set the overlap bounds: x
        if (x <= 0):
            rows_orig = [abs(shift[1]), original_dims[1]]
            rows_shift = [0, shifted_dims[1]+shift[1]]
        else:
            rows_shift = [shift[1], shifted_dims[1]]
            rows_orig = [0, original_dims[1]-shift[1]]

        # set the overlap bounds: y
        if (y <= 0):
            cols_orig = [abs(shift[0]), original_dims[0]]
            cols_shift = [0, shifted_dims[0]+shift[0]]
        else:
            cols_shift = [shift[0], shifted_dims[0]]
            cols_orig = [0, original_dims[0]-shift[0]]

        # get the relevant pixels
        original_overlap = mod_orig[cols_orig[0]:cols_orig[1], rows_orig[0]:rows_orig[1]]
        shifted_overlap = self.shifted[cols_shift[0]:cols_shift[1], rows_shift[0]:rows_shift[1]]
        self.show_overlap(original_overlap, shifted_overlap)

        return (original_overlap, shifted_overlap)

    def objective(self, parameters):
        stable_pts, warped_pts = self.find_affine(parameters)
        stable_pts = stable_pts.flatten()
        warped_pts = warped_pts.flatten()
        N = max(len(stable_pts), len(warped_pts))
        print "Number of points: " + str(N)

        if N == 0:
            return 99999999999

        score = 0.0
        for s_pt, w_pt in zip(stable_pts, warped_pts):
            score = score + ((float(s_pt) - float(w_pt))**2)

        score = score/N
        print "Objective score: " + str(score) + " for x = " + str(parameters)
        return score

    def show_overlap(self, img1, img2):
        print "Dims"
        print "   Img1 Dims: " + str(len(img1)) + " " + str(len(img1[0]))
        print "   Img2 Dims: " + str(len(img2)) + " " + str(len(img2[0]))

        dims = [min(len(img1), len(img2)), min(len(img1[0]), len(img2[0]))]

        overlap = numpy.zeros(dims)

        for x in xrange(len(overlap)):
            for y in xrange(len(overlap[0])):
                overlap[x][y] = abs(int(img1[x][y])-int(img2[x][y]))

        overlap = numpy.uint8(overlap)
        cv2.imshow("Overlapping Image", overlap)
        cv2.waitKey(500)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def _main(status):
    # read in images
    img1 = cv2.imread("data/smile_orig.png")
    img2 = cv2.imread("data/smiletest.png")
    # convert to grayscale
    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    test = toy(img1, img2)
    initial_conditions = [0.0]
    transform = optimize.minimize(test.objective, initial_conditions, method='nelder-mead', tol=1e-8)

    # Show minimization at the end
    params = transform.x
    original_img, shifted_img = test.find_affine(params)
    print "COMPLETED MINIMIZATION"
    print transform

    # show difference between transformed image and desired image
    overlap = numpy.zeros([min(len(original_img), len(shifted_img)),
                            min(len(original_img[0]), len(shifted_img[0]))])
    print "shape of overlap: " + str(overlap.shape)
    for x in xrange(len(overlap)):
        for y in xrange(len(overlap[0])):
            overlap[x][y] = abs(int(original_img[x][y])-int(shifted_img[x][y]))

    overlap = numpy.uint8(overlap)
    cv2.imshow("Overlapping Image", overlap)
    print "Final Image Shown"
    print "Dimensions: " + str(len(overlap)) + " " + str(len(overlap[0]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _main(status)
```

Images used:

Original image:
[image: original image]

Shifted and rotated image:
[image: shifted and rotated image]

Results:

```
COMPLETED MINIMIZATION
  status: 0
    nfev: 95
 success: True
     fun: 11.051886006332982
       x: array([ -1.29629630e-04,   8.42592593e-04,   2.77777778e-05])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 29
```

With the parameter mapping, the transform achieved is a x dimension shift of -1, a y dimension shift of 8, and a rotation of 0. The actual affine transform between the two images is a x dimension shift of 10, a y dimension shift of 20, and a rotation of -10.

Difference between the two images after the transform is found:
[image: difference between two images after transform]

It's close, it has a low score, but it needs to be closer (ideally perfect with a score of 0.0, or at least nothing left from the smiley face). Any suggestions would be welcome.

Related:

[Integer step size in scipy optimize minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180822/integer-step-size-in-scipy-optimize-minimize)

Comment: I noticed your code samples are from a class called toy? Could you post your complete code? I'd like to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated the post with all the relevant code.

Comment: I guess feature matching algorithms are better for your particular use case. Try some of the skimage.feature a pick the one giving better results.

Comment: I ended up using a more relevant example and got better results - instead of a smiley face, I used a Gaussian blur.