# python scipy.optimize.minimize define constraints

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, scipy, minimize

Maybe quite a specific question
I am using the scipy optimize function to get new value for seven variables. the seven value are set by the array x0 for the initial input.
`a, b, c, d` are actually `int` value.

When running the complete code and the minimize function, everything is working perfectly.

If i print how my seven variables evolve after each iteration i can see that `a, b, c, d` are converted to `float` to modify it by small step.

Though i am still getting to my final result, it would be great if i can indicate at some constraint that those 4 variable are integer only, so the optimize function would perform less iterations, and not try to set variables `a, b,c ,d` to 8.00000164 or other floating point but directly to 6,7, 8, 9, 10... for example

I am not sure it is even possible, but if anybody know how to, i'll be happy to learn.

Below is the important part of the code showing how the minimize function is setup.

```
a = 8
b = 23
c = 54
d = 89

... some code before and after

# FUNCTION - SOLVER CONSTRAINTS
def solver_constraint_1(t):
  return t[1] - t[0]
def solver_constraint_2(t):
  return t[2] - t[1]
def solver_constraint_3(t):
  return t[3] - t[2]

... some code before and after

x0 = [a, b, c, d, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

x_bounds = [[0, 20], [10, 60], [20, 80], [60, 100], [0.25, 2.5], [0.25, 2.5], [0.25, 2.5]]

x_cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': solver_constraint_1}, 
          {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': solver_constraint_2},    
          {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': solver_constraint_3})

solution = minimize(objective, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=x_bounds, constraints=x_cons, options={'ftol': 1e-8, 'maxiter': 1000, 'disp': True})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I rig SciPy's constrained optimization for integer programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793381/why-cant-i-rig-scipys-constrained-optimization-for-integer-programming)

Comment: I like the answer to the question linked above. In short: "although it seems unintuitive, integer optimization is much harder than real valued optimization". What you could do is minimize only the last three variables and do a brute-force search for the others on the 4D grid of integers. But if you actually get a useful solution don't bother, it probably won't be faster ;)

Comment: Thank you @kazemakase. From your link and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180822/integer-step-size-in-scipy-optimize-minimize i can see that other have had the same question and that there is limitation to `integer programming`. Since my code is working, i will just keep it as it is and won't try to optimize it for faster runtime.
I also like your option to minimize on 3 variable then do the brute force. Might be worth the try though each of the seven parameters have effect on each other and it might not give me the optimal solution.

Comment: That's right. To correct for the effect of parameters on each other you would have to minimize *inside* the brute force search. I guess that wold be kinda slow :)

Comment: Your convergence speed will be mostly based on the execution time of `objective` and the presence of a (fast) jacobian. I've just learned that you may even provide a jacobian for the constraints.
A different method could be a MonteCarlo approach (e.g. particle swarm), sort of a "smart" brute force.

Answer (score 0):

To give the short answer and with the help of @kazemakase in the above reply, it is simply not easily possible to fix the step size to be integer in the minimize function. Also doing `integer programming` is in fact a much complex problem to solve than the linear programming